# static text read from application properties not displaying german charector for UTF8 support

Tags: jsp, utf-8, struts-1

I used application.properties file and added German characters for some key value pairs. But when i display this value in JSP, it display as unknown characters.

Can we change the application.properties file in Struts to support utf-8. because dynamic text is displayed well on the same page.

Comment: Java properties files must be encoded in ISO-8859-1, it cannot contains any other characters. You can use `native2ascii` command line tool to convert the file or enable support for that in your IDE.

Comment: Did you find the solution? I faced the same issue.

Comment: Are you using Struts 1.x or Struts 2? You are _taggin_ your question with [tag:struts2] and [tag:struts-1].

Comment: @PaulVargas I am using Struts1.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution. Thanks there is a mistake which i did and now it gets resolved.